# How can I make these have the same levels?

Tags: r, r-markdown, logistic-regression, lda, rqda

I am running into the below error on my cm.glm line:
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.

```
# Predict using Logistic Regression
pred.glm <- ifelse(predict(fit.glm, irisTest) > 0.5, "setosa", "other")
cm.glm <- confusionMatrix(pred.glm, (irisTest$Species))
acc.glm <- cm.glm$overall['Accuracy']
prec.glm <- cm.glm$byClass['Pos Pred Value']
rec.glm <- cm.glm$byClass['Sensitivity']
```

```
# Load libraries
library(MASS)
library(caret)
library(nnet) 

# Loading iris dataset
data(iris)

# Convert it into a binary class dataset
iris$Species <- ifelse(iris$Species == "setosa", "setosa", "other")

# Split the dataset
set.seed(123)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = .8, 
                                  list = FALSE, 
                                  times = 1)
irisTrain <- iris[ trainIndex,]
irisTest  <- iris[-trainIndex,]

# Fit Logistic Regression
fit.glm <- multinom(Species ~ ., data = iris)


# Predict using Logistic Regression
pred.glm <- ifelse(predict(fit.glm, irisTest) > 0.5, "setosa", "other")
cm.glm <- confusionMatrix(pred.glm, (irisTest$Species))
acc.glm <- cm.glm$overall['Accuracy']
prec.glm <- cm.glm$byClass['Pos Pred Value']
rec.glm <- cm.glm$byClass['Sensitivity']
```

Comment: Is this a different question than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77449428/is-there-a-way-to-fix-this-error-error-in-match-argtype-arg-should-be-one?

Comment: What is the question? Why are you using `multinom` on dichotom Y?

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues with your code.

First `predict`per default gives the most likely class, to compare to a cutoff of your link function you have to use `type="probs"` as argument.

Second `confusionMatrix` expects the two arguments to be factors with the same levels. Just convert your vectors to factor. In case one of the sets does not have both factor levels (this could happen with other seeds), specify the factor levels explicitly.

Your two lines of code should then look like this:

```
pred.glm <- ifelse(predict(fit.glm, irisTest, type="probs") > 0.5, "setosa", "other")
cm.glm <- confusionMatrix(
  factor(pred.glm, levels = c("setosa", "other")), 
  factor(irisTest$Species, levels = c("setosa", "other"))
)
```